# problem with external sd card after restart

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, music-player, ringtone, external-sd

I usually store all my music, documents, and other personal files in the external sd card.

So I have my ringtone to be used from my external_sd. I've seen that if the external sd card is being in use then the ringtone is falling back to the default tone, which is a desirable feature.

But when ever I restart my device, the ringtone changes to the default one instead of the preset value, and in the settings the ringtone is shown as "Unknown Ringtone", although my sdcard is detected.

This annoying problem also causes the playlists created in the music player to not list the entries from the external sd card after the device is restarted.

Is this a bug? are anyone else facing this problem on any other device?

I really need help.

Device: Samsung Galaxy S II (non rooted)

OS: ICS (4.0.4, samsung stock)

Location of ringtone/music: /sdcard/external_sd/Music

Thanks.

Comment: Where abouts exactly on the sdcard did you put the ringtone?

Comment: @t0mm13b i've edited the question with the details of the ringtone location.