# Why does my SD data get messed up when i connect to PC with USB?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb, sd-card, ringtone, huawei

Every time I connect my phone to my computer via USB (Huawei U8666E, Android 4.0.3) even after I've disconnected my phone, the following 2 things happen (that I can tell): My ringtone goes back to "Default" (i'm using a custom one which is saved on the SD memory) and my music playlist (the only one i have) goes empty. No music file is missing, they're just removed from the playlist, and they, too, are on my SD memory.

What can i do to fix or circumvent the issue?

Edit: The problem is not that it happens while the phone is hooked on the computer, but that it persists AFTER i disconnect it. In other words, after disconnecting the phone, i have to manually rebuild my playlists and change the ringtone again. Is there a way for me to transfer data between PC and phone without having to "reconfigure" the phone after the process? Or better yet a way to use the USB normally without the "reconfiguring" having to take place?

Comment: Same issue [in this place](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/39728/16575) -- unfortunately now answer either...

Comment: Guy below seems to be up to something, BUT not there yet.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your ROM doesn't properly reset settings when the sdcard is re-enabled (since it obviously becomes unavailable to the OS when using USB Mass Storage). Unfortunately, this is likely an issue with your ROM and I don't think there is a likely setting that would fix it.

However, in Android 3.0, Google added MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) support and it has been in all versions since. This allows the sdcard to remain mounted in the Android system while also allowing it to be accessed on the computer. I can't remember the exact layout of ICS, but to be able to change it to MTP from UMS, it is probably pretty close to `Settings -> Storage -> Menu -> USB Computer Connection -> enable MTP`

Comment: Sadly, no changeable options under the "storage" entry (no menu), only data exposition. Any other ideas where it might be? Also, what is UMS? Not a very technical guy (yet), managed to read the other ones but not this :P

Comment: UMS is just the acronym for USB Mass Storage (an acronym within an acronym... gotta love it). But you should have access to a submenu within your storage section. Does your device have a menu key? If it does, press that, if not, there should be a 3 dot "action overflow" menu button somewhere on the screen. If your manufacturer for some strange reason removed that, you might be able to get MTP working with [Multi-Mount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rafoid.multimountsdcard.widget.free) (I don't think root is required for MTP)

Comment: UMS stands for [USB Mass Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Mass_Storage), where the mounting device (here: computer) gets physical access to the mounted storage (here: SDCard), while with MTP only logical access is given.

Comment: Sadly, my options are "Software update", a detailed report on SD and Internal memory allocation, and complete erasure of either. The menu button, although available, does nothing in this screen. I will investigate the aplication you linked. Anything else?

Comment: No juice with the app. It crashes as soon as i connect the cable, leaving me connected via Mass Storage and causing the typical aftereffects :/ Any other ideas on turning on MTP?

Comment: Unless a more solid solution comes up, i will simply refrain from using the USB to link up with my PC *sigh* If anyone knows a free substitute app for some different sort of connection worth mention, please go ahead (And of course, if you have another way to solve the issue)

Comment: There are a number of wireless options for you to access your content. Although, I am a bit rusty on most since I mainly used [Samba Filesharing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba) which can only work with root-enabled devices. But I have heard AirDroid mentioned multiple times and that might be something worth trying.

Answer (score -1):

In `Settings > Storage > press the menu key > USB connection > MTP connection`.

Answer (score -1):

well i know this is a year late but i was having the same problems on my phone (huawei y300-01) all my apps would b moved around, and pages were sometimes created. i saw that whenever i connected the phone the various USB options would pop up (MTP, PTP and installer). i used to choose PTP as it was the only way to access the SDcard. I decided to try installer and found some drivers in the folder that opened up, installed them and now MTP works fine, my apps dont move around anymore after disconecting the phone.